In pine Script, how to specify a specific code snippet at the last "candle"
Such as python Code:
A = []
z = 0
for i in range(1, 11):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        A.append(i)
maxA = max(A)
for y in range(maxA):
    z = z + math.pow(1.2, y)
print(z)

>>> 25.958

In this python code, I first find the even numbers from 1 to 10, then find the maximum value "10", then calculate 1.2^0+...1.2^9, and finally get the result
Now in Pine Script Code: I defined the long and short strategies, and used an array to record the number of consecutive losses, found the maximum value of the array in the last "candle", and then used the "for to" statement to calculate the data. Similar to For the above python code
I think that the code in Pine Script will be executed once every trading day ("candle"), but I need some code snippets to complete the "long" and "short" in the specified time interval and then be executed at the end. How to implement in Pine Script so that certain codes are executed last after all work is completed?
Just like "net profit" and "win rate", the result is determined at the end.

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
Could you please share your code and if possible, some screen captures so that we can better understand the issue.

@Gu5tavo71 Hello Gu5tavo71, This is part of my codeURL:https://cn.tradingview.com/script/y0vfLUvE/
My goal is to find out how much money I invested after losing X times in a row.My current code can achieve this goal. The VIX index did lose 5 times in a row within the specified date range.  BUT I think we should know the maximum number of losses (X) at the end of the backtest, and then use this X to calculate the total investment amount using (for...to...).  I want to know how to make the pine script understand that some code is executed at the end and only once
